# Issue of having more Topic Partitions than Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create an active/active cluster. So my Consumers need to subscribe to the original as well as the replicated topics. So the number of partitions will be double of what is initially used in a single cluster setup. Will this increase in the partitions cause issue to my consumers. Sometimes the replicated topic might not receive message.

The Number of Consumers will always be less than the number of Partitions.

Will consumers subscribing to ideal patitions(Partitions that might not receive messages) cause latency or any performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

> cause issue to my consumers

No. You can still have up-to the number of total partitions being consumed (for all topics) active instances of a consumer app.

> Number of Consumers will always be less than the number of Partitions

That is not the most optimal way to guarantee minimal lag.

> cause latency or any performance issue?

No more than without active/active replication.